# What is a good algorithm for traversing outward from a point on a 2D grid?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Suppose I have a 2D array where 0,0 is in the top left corner and the bottom is say 100,100. I have a point in that array such as 10,10. I want to do a test on each element that is 1 away from this point so a 3x3 box. If all my tests fail I want to move out one more rectangular ring so now it would be a 5x5 box.  But I want to be efficient so I don't want to test the 3x3 box again just the new boxes. I've thought of maybe having a starting vector like up and then moving in a snake like pattern clockwise until I come back around then incrementing and doing it again but I'm not sure if that's the best. I've also thought of just scanning left to right but I don't want to scan row 8,8 if the answer was already found in row 9,9.

A grid would look something like this with the starting point in the middle

```
8,8   9,8   10,8   11,8   12,8
8,9   9,9   10,9   11,9   12,9
8,10  9,10  10,10  11,10  12,10
8,11  9,11  10,11  11,11  12,11
8,12  9,12  10,12  11,12  12,12
```

This is just for a cover checking algorithm for a hobby game I'm working on. In my example I've already found a source of cover at 10,10. Now I just want to search all the squares around it and test if the player can see me, and if not then I've found a good spot on my grid to hide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Suppose you start at the red square (i,j) and need to check for a cover. You need to do what you are asking for. Check each surrounding rectangle.

Start from index (i-1, j-1). Do a test on the green squares.
If not found,  start from index (i-2, j-2). Do a test on the blue squares.
If not found,  start from index (i-3, j-3). Do a test on the yellow squares.

In some cases, instead of (i-1, j-1) you might have to go for (i-1, j) or (i, j-1).

[image]

[image]

The algorithm is not tricky here, but implementation is. Don't cross the matrix borders.

Relevant links:

1. [Print a given matrix in spiral form](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/)
2. [Construct a matrix with numbers 1 to m*n in spiral way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-matrix-construct-a-matrix-with-numbers-1-to-mn-in-spiral-way/)

The above links have inward spiral. You need to similarly do for outward spiral.